# Render bug with NSSlider within NSPopover in dark mode

Tags: nspopover, nsslider

Is it me or there is an bug with `NSSlider` when it is a subview of an `NSPopover` view?

Here's the code I use:

```
popover = NSPopover.new;
        popover.contentViewController = NSViewController.new;
        NSView *view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 100)];
        NSSlider *slider = [[NSSlider alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(20, 50, 150, 30)];
        slider.numberOfTickMarks = 6;
        [view addSubview:slider];
        popover.contentViewController.view = view;
[popover showRelativeToRect:self.frame ofView:self.view preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
```

And this is how the `NSSlider` renders:

[image]

See how the tick marks are off-center. EDIT: the issue only appears in dark mode.

The same `NSView` (not an equivalent view, the very same `NSView`) set as the `contentView` in a `NSWindow` renders the slider properly like below (don't pay attention to the darker background):

[image]

Any idea what's going on? Whether I design the popover's view in IB or in code, this doesn't change anything. Nor does modifying the number of tick marks, layout contrains, or whatever I tried.
This is on Monterey 13.2

And incidentally, any idea what the `tickMarkPosition` property of `NSSlider` is supposed to do? The doc seems clear, but on a slider that renders normally, the tick mark position is neither above nor below the slider, it's just centred (see second image). And changing the property has absolutely no effect on the tick mark position.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think the `tickMarkPosition` property isn't used anymore. Have you tried light mode?

Comment: Who would have thought? The issue does not appear in light mode.